# How to push_back existing objects to a vector of shared pointers?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, stdvector

Using raw pointers, I can create a vector of pointers and push_back addresses like so:

```
Entity objEntity;
std::vector<Entity*> Entities;
Entities.push_back(&objEntity);
```

If I instead use a vector of shared pointers:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity>> Entities;
```

... how do I push_back the addresses?

From what I understand, std::shared_ptr::reset is used in order to assign the address of an existing object to a smart pointer. Do I need to first create a temporary pointer, call reset, and then push_back?

```
std::shared_ptr<Entity> temp;
temp.reset(&objEntity);
Entities.push_back(temp);
```

Comment: Why not push_back(make_shared(objEntity)) ?

Comment: when you use push_back a copy constructor is called.

Comment: @Clonk only if you pass an lvalue reference to it.

Comment: If you want it to perform then prefer Boost.PolyCollection to smart pointer vectors (it usually wins since it fragments memory less) and if you can't use boost for whatever reason then use vector of unique_ptr to get rid of double indirection and other overhead of shared_ptr.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to construct a new shared pointer from an existing pointer:

```
Entity* entity = new Entity;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity>> Entities;
Entities.emplace_back(entity);
```

Alternatively you can use `push_back` to construct the object with `make_shared`.

```
Entities.push_back(std::make_shared<Entity>());
```

There is no way to safely add existing objects (that were not created as pointers to begin with). You can add an existing pointer, or make a copy when you create the shared pointer.

If you add the address of an existing object, you will attempt to free the memory twice, because the destructor of the shared pointer destroys the object:

```
Entity entity;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity>> Entities;
Entities.emplace_back(&entity); // incorrect usage
// What happens when entity and shared pointer both go out of scope??
```

Comment: I will accept this as the answer since it explained to me why I shouldn't do what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 7):

When creating smart pointers, it's best to go with their `std::make_*` functions. `vector::push_back` is overloaded for rvalue references, invoking it like this

```
Entities.push_back(std::make_shared<Entity>());
```

will hence construct an element in the vector by moving the `std::shared_ptr` you passed in, hence no performance hit due to modifying the control block of the smart pointer here. Note also that `vector::emplace_back` can't be used with `std::make_shared` but instead only with a raw pointer, which should be avoided for the sake of exception handling and brevity (passing a raw pointer requires to manually create an `Entity` instance on the heap).